# Error: @resource annotations must provide a name

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly

I am trying to deploy my spring boot app to wildfly, but unfortunately I got an error. By the way my springboog version is 2.0.2, and I tried wildfly 10,11,12, all the same. Below was the error message

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."smartcall.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service
.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."smartcall.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "smartcall.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYEE0020: @Resource annotations must provide a name.
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor.processClassResource(ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor.java:194)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor.deploy(ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor.java:146)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
        ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `@Resource` annotation is on a type it requires a name. If it's on a field the name should not be required.